# Looking for Cause of Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm sure there's something simple behind the error Null Pont Exception error I am getting, but, I don't see it. Here's the relevant code:

```
package com.example.gameexpensetracker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Chart_screen_activity extends Activity {       

    double strategyTotalDB;
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this); 



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chart_screen_activity);
        db.open();  
    pieGraphData();
    }  

       public void pieGraphData() {
                    Cursor cursor17 = db.rawQuery("SELECT (strategy_total) FROM strategyTotal WHERE _id=(SELECT max(_id) FROM strategyTotal)",
                    null);
        if (cursor17.moveToFirst()){ 
        strategyTotalDB = cursor17.getDouble(0);
        cursor17.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "New entry"+strategyTotalDB+ "added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
        }}}
```

The LogCat says lines 23 and 32 are causing the problem:

```
12-29 10:46:39.979: D/AndroidRuntime(1754): Shutting down VM
12-29 10:46:39.979: W/dalvikvm(1754): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gameexpensetracker/com.example.gameexpensetracker.Chart_screen_activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.example.gameexpensetracker.Chart_screen_activity.pieGraphData(Chart_screen_activity.java:32)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at com.example.gameexpensetracker.Chart_screen_activity.onCreate(Chart_screen_activity.java:23)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-29 10:46:39.989: E/AndroidRuntime(1754):     ... 11 more
```

Here's my DBAdapter:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBAdapter {
    static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_PLATFORM = "platform";
    static final String KEY_GENRE = "genre";
    static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    static final String KEY_TOTAL = "total";
    static final String KEY_WHEREBOUGHT = "wherebought";
    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gamesDB";
    static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "purchases";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchases(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "title text , platform text, genre text , date text , price double , wherebought text );";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grandTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS strategyTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "strategy_prices double, strategy_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE4 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adventureTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "adventure_prices double, adventure_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE5 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actionTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "action_prices double, action_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE6 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MMOTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "mmo_prices double, mmo_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE7 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS racingTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "racing_prices double, racing_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE8 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS rpgTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "rpg_prices double, rpg_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE9 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simulationTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "simulation_prices double, simulation_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE10 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sportsTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "sports_prices double, sports_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE11 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS otherTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "other_prices double, other_total double);";

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE12 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS puzzleTotal(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "puzzle_prices double, puzzle_total double);";


    double columntotal, strategyPriceInput, actionPriceInput, adventurePriceInput, MMOPriceInput, racingPriceInput, rpgPriceInput, simulationPriceInput, 
    sportsPriceInput, puzzlePriceInput, otherPriceInput;



    final Context context;

    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE3);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE4);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE5);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE6);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE7);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE8);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE9);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE10);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE11);
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE12);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE2);
        }
    }

    // ---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // ---closes the database---
    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    // ---insert a record into the database---
    public long insertRecord(String title, String platform, String genre,
            String date, double price, String wherebought) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PLATFORM, platform);
        initialValues.put(KEY_GENRE, genre);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
        initialValues.put(KEY_WHEREBOUGHT, wherebought);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);

    }





    // delete all records

    public void deleteAll() {
        context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

    }

    // ---deletes a particular record---
    public boolean deleteRecord(long rowId) {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    // ---retrieves all the records---
    public Cursor getAllRecords() {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_GENRE, KEY_DATE, KEY_PRICE, KEY_WHEREBOUGHT }, null, null,
                null, null, null);
    }

    // ---retrieves a particular record---
    public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_PLATFORM, KEY_GENRE, KEY_DATE,
                KEY_PRICE, KEY_WHEREBOUGHT }, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    // ---updates a record---
    public boolean updateRecord(long rowId, String title, String platform,
            String genre, String date, double price, String wherebought) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(KEY_PLATFORM, platform);
        args.put(KEY_GENRE, genre);
        args.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        args.put(KEY_PRICE, price);
        args.put(KEY_WHEREBOUGHT, wherebought);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor rawQuery(String string, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }




}
```

Comment: I updated the post with the DBAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DBAdapter.rawQuery()` is not implemented, it's just a stub that returns `null`. Attempting to call `moveToFirst()` on this `null` reference causes the NPE.

That is, change

```
public Cursor rawQuery(String string, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

to something like

```
public Cursor rawQuery(String sql, String[] args) {
    return db.rawQuery(sql, args);
}
```

Comment: But why wouldn't it be implemented? Is there some way to correct this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do we know why it's not implemented?  You wrote the code!

Comment: Wow! Thanks! That did the trick! I think I see now what you meant by it not being implemented. The original method in the DBAdapter was not constructed to handle the the query I was try to post to the db, right?

Comment: Likely what happened was that Eclipse complained about a missing method being called and as a quick fix offered to create a stub for it and the OP chose it without paying too much attention to what actually happened. Compile-time error replaced with a runtime error, yay!

Answer (score 1):

Move db initialization to `onCreate`

```
DBAdapter db; 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.chart_screen_activity);
db = new DBAdapter(this);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. But now, after moving the db initialization, it can no long resolve "db" and it flags each instance that it's used as red...

Comment: @user3116503 check the edit. Declare db as a instance variable. Since it was declared and initialized in onCreate it was local to oncreate ie available only in onCreate. So declare it as instance variable and it should work

Comment: To make it an instance variable, would I just move it up to just after the public class is declared? Sorry, I am just starting to learn android. :(

Comment: @user3116503 just as showed in my post outside `onCreate` inside the activity class

Comment: This is generally good advice but does not solve the OP's problem. (Passing pre-`onCreate()` `Context` to `SQLiteOpenHelper` constructor is one of the cases where it isn't a problem - the context is only used when the database is opened, the constructor just stores the reference.)

Comment: @laalto agreed. Should have taken a closer look at the post

Answer (score 1):

It seems the variable `cursor17` is null. Maybe in your situation this changed if-condition helps:

```
if (cursor17 != null && cursor17.moveToFirst()) {
```

I don't know your DBAdapter class, but is the second parameter to your rawQuery()-method not set to null, meaning you get null if your table strategyTotal is empty? I would look if the table is empty and why and what result your query will then deliver.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The table is not empty, though. There are several records in it. I did try making the edit you suggested, and no errors are generated, but nothing seems to happen after a certain point, as I never see the toast appear...